# Find the Conditional Expectation in this case

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Suppose that the joint density for two random variables is given by

$$ f(x,y) =  \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}} e^{-y}}{y} $$ where $x,y \in (0, \infty)^2$.

Find the $E(X|Y=y),~$ $\forall y > 0$.

My solution:

I would like to find it using the conditional density so I started as $E(X|Y=y) = \int_0^{\infty} y~ f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)dy$

Then, I found the conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x | y)$ for $X$ given that $Y = y,~  \forall y > 0$.

Using the definition, $f_{X|Y}(x | y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$.

First to find the marginal of $Y$ from the joint as $$f_Y(y)= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}} e^{-y}}{y} dx = e^{-y}. $$

Following, 
$$f_{X|Y}(x | y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}} e^{-y}}{y}}{e^{-y}} = \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}} }{y}$$

Finally, $E(X|Y=y) = \int_0^{\infty} y~ f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)dy = \int_0^{\infty} y \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}} }{y} dy $

but the integral doesn't converge. What is wrong in my solution?

EDIT: I think I did a mistake here $E(X|Y=y) = \int_0^{\infty} y~ f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)dy$ and the it should be as $E(X|Y=y) = \int_0^{\infty} x~ f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)dx = \int_0^{\infty} x \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}} }{y} dx = y$

Is this true? Also what is the difference between $E(X/Y)$ and $E(X/Y=y)$ or $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $f_{X,Y=y}(x,y)$ ? thanks for help

Comment: Yes, it is true. Moreover, the structure of joint pdf prompts the answer. It is $e^{-y}\cdot \frac{1}{y}e^{-\frac{1}{y}x} = f_Y(y)\cdot f_{X|Y}(x|y)$, where $Y$ has exponential distribution with expectation $1$ and $X$ given $Y=y$ has exponential distribution with mean $y$. So the answer is $y$.

Comment: @NCh thanks a lot. Could you please clarify what is the difference by saying _the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$_ and  _the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$_ ?

Comment: This words means almost the same. We can say that conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is exponential with parameter $1/Y$, and this means exactly the same as *when $Y$ takes value $y$, the conditional distribution of $X$ is exponenial with parameter $1/y$*.

Comment: And also: there is a difference between $E(X|Y)$ and $E(X|Y=y)$. The first is a random variable which is a function of random variable $Y$: 
$$E(X|Y)=h(Y)$$ 
The second is $h(y)=E(X|Y=y)$. 
To find the first, you need firstly to find $h(y)$ and then take $Y$ instead of $y$.

Comment: @NCh So according to what you wrote firstly above, if I need to calculate $p(X>1 / Y=y)$, I should do 

$$ p(X>1 / Y=y) = \frac{\int_1^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx}{\int_0^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx} =  \frac{\int_1^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-x/y} e^{-y} } {y}dx}{ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-x/y} e^{-y}}{y} dx} = e^{-1/y}$$ do i a understand the definitions well !

Comment: Yes, your calculations are right.

Answer (score 1):

$E(X|Y=y)=\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty}{xf(x,y)}dx}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{f(x,y)}dx}$

$E(X|Y=y)=\frac{\frac{e^{-y}}{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}{xe^{-\frac{x}{y}}dx}}{\frac{e^{-y}}{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}dx}$

$E(X|Y=y)=\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty}{xe^{-\frac{x}{y}}dx}}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}dx}$

$E(X|Y=y)=\frac{-y(\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}{x}d{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}})}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}dx}$

$E(X|Y=y)=\frac{-y([xe^{-\frac{x}{y}}]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}dx)}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}dx}$

$E(X|Y=y)=y\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}dx}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}dx}$

$E(X|Y=y)=y$